# What does “Camp mayor” mean?

Tags: meaning

In the TV show *Inside Bill’s Brain* there was a conversation between director and Bill Gates S1:E1:

Director asking: “Favorite memory from Camp Cheerio.”
Bill answers: “Uh, you know, having my dad... who’s the mayor...”

I found the meaning of “mayor” in [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mayor):

> The mayor of a town or city is the person who has been elected to
>   represent it for a fixed period of time or, in some places, to run its
>   government.

What does “Camp Mayor” mean? Camp is neither a town nor a city.

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: Please quote the context where you found this. It could be the leader of a camp (say a youth camp or a scout camp), or perhaps a mayor who’s taken to be particularly [camp](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/camp#Adjective) himself… without knowing the context, there’s no way to tell what it’s supposed to mean in the place where you found it.

Comment: I just updated the question, thanks for advice.

Comment: In the excerpt you’ve given here, it doesn’t sound like anyone’s talking about a camp mayor to me. It sounds like Bill is saying that his father is mayor (of a town, presumably the one they live in) as an aside to the anecdote he’s about to tell.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought, then I searched on the internet and found that Bill Gates’s father was a [lawyer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates_Sr.), not a mayor.

Comment: Mayors can be  citizens in any occupation.  For example, lawyers.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the person or the people in charge of the camp.

> The terms base camp mayor, or mayoral cell will be used to describe the individual or organizational staff and structure in charge of the internally focused operations and administration of a single base camp, including the related aspects of master planning, construction, operations and management, facilities ..

https://adminpubs.tradoc.army.mil › pamphlets

Comment: Please can you find something to back up this?

Comment: Better? @marcellothearcane

Comment: Better – but remember to also cite your source by adding a link to where you found it and giving the name of the site/page/dictionary/whatever.

Comment: Perfect! Have a +1

Answer (score -1):

The OP provides very little about this, so we can only guess.

[definitions from [LEXICO](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/camp)]

> **camp** ADJECTIVE
>   1.1 Deliberately exaggerated and theatrical in style.

So perhaps a "camp mayor" is someone performing comically, imitating a mayor.

> **camp** NOUN
>   1.2 (North American) A summer holiday programme for children, offering a range of activities.

So perhaps such a camp will have (or select) a person to serve as "mayor".  That would be the "camp mayor".

We could go on, finding more possibilities.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context, I just updated the question. I’m very sorry  :(